# Why is this Background.ts Chrome Extension script not installing with this Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, es6-promise

I am trying to initialize my localStorage using a Promise when I install/load/reload my Chrome Extension, but for some reason, this `ModelDataColdSet` call is preventing the Background script from running. I'm using Node 16.14.2.

`ModelData.ts`

```
export interface ModelData {
  cold?: Object
}

export type ModelDataKeys = keyof ModelData

export const ModelDataColdDefault = {}

export function ModelDataColdSet(cold: Object): Promise<void> {
  const values: ModelData = {
    cold,
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set(values, () => {
      resolve()
    })
  })
}

export function ModelDataColdGet(): Promise<Object> {
  const keys: ModelDataKeys[] = ["cold"]
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(keys, (res: ModelData) => {
      resolve(res.cold ?? {})
    })
  })
}
```

When I delete the `ModelDataColdSet(ModelDataColdDefault)` line and the Background script will run and print `[Background]` to the console. All of the tutorials I've found said this is the way to do it so I'm confused.

`Background.ts`

```
import { ModelDataColdDefault     , ModelDataColdSet }
  from './ModelData';
console.log('[Background]');

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Initializing extension');
  ModelDataColdSet(ModelDataColdDefault);
  
  chrome.alarms.create("FeedUpdate", {
    periodInMinutes: 1/60,
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "FeedAddSelectionContextMenu",
    "title": "Add selection to broadcast.",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id": "FeedAddPageContextMenu",
    "title": "Add current page to your mom."
  });
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  console.log('[onAlarm.FeedUpdate]');
  if (alarm.name === "FeedUpdate") {
    console.log('[onAlarm.FeedUpdate]');
  }
});
```

Comment: Use devtools to debug the problem. [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)

Answer (score 0):

Using my dev configuration, which is React 18.2.0 and Node 16.4.2, the `chrome.storage` doesn't when I call `ModelDataColdSet({})`, `chrome.storage.sync.set({ cold: ModelDataColdDefault })`, or `ModelDataColdSet(ModelDataColdDefault)` in the `Background.js` script, but it works when I initialize it like

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('Initializing extension');
  
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ cold: {} });
}
```

But the code will work if I copy the functions and default const values from `ModelData.ts` into `Background.ts`, but they don't work when I load them from the `ModelData.ts` in `Background.ts`. I have no clue why this is happening. It's just downright strange. Please drop a comment below. Thanks.